# Commit transaction after Client acknowledge mechanism on Apache and PHP server

Tags: php, apache

I get some important data from the client and sometimes the client gets disconnected in the middle of the process of sending it to the server. The client keeps sending these data until it is confirmed by the server that the data has been saved and processed in the server. When the client disconnects in the middle of the server processing (after it sent the data, but before it got a response) the server will save the data while the client would keep trying to send this data again. Is there a way to commit changes in the server side only when I know the client has received the server's response?

Comment: when the client received the data ask the client to return 1 else return 0.

Comment: There is promise in node for these kind of issues. does promise works in php? http://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/components/promise.html